# Unable to install SQLite3 gem on Ruby 1.9.3, no issues with Ruby 2.0.0. What's the difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

Like the title says...
I've been teaching myself RoR the past few weeks and I'm confused about something.
I went through the tutorial [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) no problem. No issues installing gems or anything. Now I've decided to learn more from [this book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). So I installed 1.9.3 with rvm and found myself unable to install SQLite3.

What's the issue? It installed fine on the newer version and once I switched back to Ruby 2.0.0 I had no issues installing that version of SQLite. If it helps, I'm on Mac OS 10.6.8.

Here's the Terminal output from my failures:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/ME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no 
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/ME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
--with-sqlite3-dir
--without-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
--enable-local
--disable-local
--with-sqlite3lib
--without-sqlite3lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3 p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3 1.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

if you are using using debian bases distro.

```
sudo yum install sqlite-devel
```

if you are using redhat based distro.

do gem install sqlite3 after that. That should work

I never used a mac but use rvm to install rails. on the command line hit `rvm requirements` and install all the packages listed there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. If you don't mind resetting your gems, then follow the option below.

Go to the below link and download the installer for your operating system.

It installs everything perfectly and quickly all in 1 working package.

http://railsinstaller.org/